# Java : Simple Loop

Tags: java, loops

Here is a simple version without any loops. How can I make it loop like "Wrong password. Try again." until user puts the right password instead stopping the program
(or give them 3 chances before it stops)?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class helloworld2
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
        long Pass;
        boolean auth = true;

        System.out.println("Enter Password :");
        Pass = q.nextLong();

        if ( Pass != 1234 )
           {
           System.out.println("Wrong Password!");
           auth = false;
           }
        else
           {
           System.out.println("Password Confirmed.");
           auth = true;
           }

        if (auth) {
            ////blablabla
            }

        else
          {
            return;
          }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need [`do`-`while` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: variable names musn't be capitalized (`Pass`) That's for class names.

Comment: Just a simple note: Read the Java Sun convention =)

Comment: Bad idea to do things in the main method, its static definition makes it impossible to access non-static fields, instead instantiate a new helloworld2 object and define your behavior in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class helloworld2
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
        long Pass;
        boolean auth = true;
        boolean rightPassword = false;
        while(!rightPassword){//repeat until passwort is correct
          System.out.println("Enter Password :");
          Pass = q.nextLong();

          if ( Pass != 1234 )
          {
            System.out.println("Wrong Password!");
            auth = false;
          }
          else
          {
            rightPassword = true;//let the loop finish
            System.out.println("Password Confirmed.");
            auth = true;
          }
        }
        // Here do what you want to do
        //because here the user has entered a right password                 
    }
}
```